# C++ Maps, How these two declarations are not correct?

Tags: c++, pointers, maps

I am using map to store elements and I need to allocate a dynamic map memory such that I can pass this memory to caller function without any hassle however the following code snippet is confusing me. Have a look here.

```
std :: map <int, int> map1;
map1[some_integer_x] = some_integer_y; // OK at compilation.
```

But following snippet is not OK and gives error.

```
std :: map <int, int> * map2 = new std :: map <int, int>
map2[some_integer_x] = some_integer_y; // Not OK at compilation.
```

Here is the error it gives me on GCC 5.

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::map<int, int>’ and ‘int’)
map2[some_integer_x] = some_integer_y;
```

I can understand that this is related to some pointers issue. What can be reason? What are my other options? I want to pass map without involving a copy as map will contain huge amount of information.

Comment: You need to dereference your pointer `(*map2)[some_integer_x]` By the way, you probably do not need to make a dynamic map, what is your usage?

Comment: ah, nice spotted. Thanks it worked.

Comment: BTW you can pass the map *by reference* to avoid copying or you can *move* the map using `std::move` to avoid copying without resorting to dynamic creation.

Comment: _to pass map_ define to pass. You can take the address of a variable.

Comment: You almost never want to allocate the map itself dynamically. The map object is quite small, and usually it is doing all of the memory management for the contents of the map for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map2` is a pointer to `map`.

To access the `std::map::operator[]` you need to dereference the pointer first, using the operator `*`.

Because `[]` has higher operator precedence than `*`, you need to write

```
(*map2)[some_integer_x] = some_integer_y;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `map2` is a pointer, then `operator[]` works the same way as for an array of `std::map<int, int>`.

The line :

```
map2[some_integer_x] = some_integer_y;
```

Means "go to the element `some_integer_x` and assign the to it value `some_integer_y`".

That causes the compilation error of mismatched type, because 
type of `map2[some_integer_x]` is `std::map<int, int>` you are trying to assign an integer value to it.

So, the first of all you need to deference the pointer:

```
(*map2)[some_integer_x] = some_integer_y;
```

Comment: Yes, map2[0][some_integer_x] = some_integer_y do works.

Answer (score 1):

You are operating on the pointer to a map as if it were an instance of a map.  You need to dereference the pointer before use like in the example below:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  std :: map <int, int> map1;
  map1[1] = 2;   
  std::map<int, int> *map2 = new std::map<int, int>();
  (*map2)[1] = 3;   
  std::cout << "Map1 at location 1 is: " << map1[1] << std::endl; //Prints 2
  std::cout << "Map2 at location 1 is: " << (*map2)[1] << std::endl; // Prints 3
  delete map2;
}
```